# Edit cart in last step of ecommerce checkout

Tags: e-commerce, checkout

I'm working on a commerce which has 3 steps in its checkout process. The last step is confirm your order. 
In the previous steps I ask users data and billing information and,in the last step, user can reviews these info before make a purchase. The shopping cart is always visible during all steps. I have a doubt. I have to allow users to edit his order in the last step of checkout? because I read that the step "confirm your order" does not allows to  edit the order itself in a direct way (with +/- buttons on items or the button for remove one item from the cart). Of course, there should be a way to do it (as a link named "edit your order", to edit quantity, remove items etc) but the last step shouldn't allow to edit these info in a direct way. Because the previous steps allow it, what do you think that I should do?Not allow direct edit at all in all steps or always allow in all 3 steps?
I Hope I was clear
Thank you

Comment: You should also check with regulations for the targeted customer's countries. AFAIK in my country you have to show a summary of your order before actually ordering. I.e. if you would allow a change for German customers you would still be forced to show it one more time before the actual order.

Answer (score 1):

The last step is only meant to review and confirm the order, not to change it.

By making it read-only and not editable, you give the user more confidence in that he/she does not change something by accident, just before finally confirming the order.

So I suggest to have the last step read-only and offer a link "Change order" or "I want to change the order" that takes the user back one step.

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't want to fall in a lack of consistence through the interface. In addition, if I take the user back one step, this step is not direct related to the editing of the order. With more clarity : if you are in the last step and you want to change your order, you click on the link that takes you back one step. This is the step where you provided your billing info, so the reaction could be : "wtf, I want to change my order not my billing info". Maybe, allowing to edit the order through a modal which overlays in the last step could be better?

Comment: You could also turn the last step into an editable mode if the user wants to make changes.

When in the editable mode, you can leave it with a button ala "I am done changing my order". Doing so will re-activate the button to make the final confirmation.